# Angulartics loads many unused scripts

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, bower, angulartics

I installed [Angulartics](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics) using Bower for Google Analytics support:

```
bower install --save angulartics
bower install --save angulartics-google-analytics
```

Unfortunately, my `index.html` file is now cluttered with a ton of scripts that don't need to be loaded:

```
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-clicky.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-cnzz.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-ga-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-gtm.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-piwik.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-splunk.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-woopra.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-marketo.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-intercom.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-inspectlet.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-newrelic-insights.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to install Angulartics for *just one* of these (in my case Google Analytics)?

Answer (score 0):

For google analytics, you only need two Angulartics script files.

> 1. angulartics.min.js
> 2. angulartics-google-analytics.min.js

Just reference only these in your page and it will work fine. Angulartics support so many vendors not only Google Analytics, the rest are the plugins to enable other vendors tracking.

Comment: I can certainly make it work manually. My question is how to make it work with bower, which automates versioning, dependencies, CDN paths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use wiredep grunt plugin you can use exclude option to make sure that unsed files won't end up in your distribution.
Just add the following to your Gruntfile.js:

```
wiredep: {
   app: {
       exclude: [
           '/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-baidu.js',
           '/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-clicky.js',
           '/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-cnzz.js',
           '/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-ga-cordova.js',
           '/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-gtm.js',
           '/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-inspectlet.js',
           '/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-intercom.js',
           '/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-marketo.js',
           etc...
       ]
    }
}
```